# Material calendar how to select max and min date?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

I am using material calendar and i want user to select one month date only. I use `minData` and `maxDate` field. `minDate` is working but `maxDate` not working.

exmple.component.html

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onCalendarSelectedChange($event)" [minDate]="today" [maxDate]="maxDate"></mat-calendar>
```

Here is the given link:

https://angular-pknsri.stackblitz.io

Please help me.

Comment: please share a minimal reproducible example in `stackblitz.com`

Comment: you tagged angular-material, but it has only datepicker. SO which library are you using?

Comment: @FarhatZaman https://angular-pknsri.stackblitz.io please check.

Comment: @KiraAG https://angular-pknsri.stackblitz.io please check.

Comment: @SampatSingh can you give us the edit mode for the stackblitz link?

Comment: please share `editor URL` not `app URL`.

Comment: @KiraAG Please check [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pknsri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @FarhatZaman Please check [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pknsri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: actually you overriding current by adding +1 in month that's why it was not working just replace your code with my code.

`var CurrentDate = new Date();
    this.minDate = CurrentDate;
    var FutureDate = new Date();
    this.maxDate  = new Date(FutureDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth()+1));`

and after adding +1 in month it was converting in second so i just parsed it in `new Date()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have change the stackblitz with anil's answer. So i am updating what could have possibly gone wrong. You should create two different date objects for min and max separately.

```
 var minCurrentDate = new Date();
    var maxNewDate = new Date();
    this.minDate = minCurrentDate;
    this.maxDate  = maxNewDate.setMonth(maxNewDate.getMonth()+1);

    // this.minDate = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
    // this.maxDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
    console.log(this.maxDate, minCurrentDate,maxNewDate, maxNewDate.getMonth());
```

When you did setMonth() on the current date you changed the reference for min date as well. Both your minDate and max date were pointing to the same thing. After all object was the same, only the references changed. So try creating two different objects and check.

PS: Farhat raced me :P. I didn't see it.

Comment: hahaha no problem mate, it doesn't matter, after all, we all are here trying to help others.

Answer (score 1):

in html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

in ts file

```
 minDate = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
  maxDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
```

Reference
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples